# Prepending initial state to a quantum circuit in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-phase-estimation, initialization

I am trying to generate a Quantum Phase Estimation (QPE) circuit in QISKIT the following way.

1 - First, I generate a QPE circuit with the following code:

```
### building inverse quantum fourier transform circuit
iqft = StandardIQFTS(2)
iqft_circ = QuantumCircuit(QuantumRegister(2))
iqft.construct_circuit(mode='circuit', qubits=iqft_circ.qubits, circuit=iqft_circ, do_swaps=True)

### Defining matrix operator
matrix = np.array([[1,0],[0,np.exp(1j*np.pi/4)]])

### Defining Quantum Phase Estimation object
eigs_qpe = EigsQPE(MatrixOperator(matrix=matrix),
                   iqft,
                   num_time_slices=2,
                   num_ancillae=2,
                   expansion_mode='trotter',
                   expansion_order=1,
                   evo_time=2,
                   negative_evals=False,
                   ne_qfts=[None,None])

### Generating circuit
eigs_circ = eigs_qpe.construct_circuit(mode="circuit")
eigs_circ.draw(output="mpl")
```

2 - Then I want to prepend the following initial state to the previous circuit

```
vector = np.array([0,1])
initial_state = Custom(1,state_vector=vector)
```

Thus getting a QPE computed on the `initial_state`. Is it possible to do this, for example by accessing `eigs_circ.data` and prepending the proper gates that generate the `initial_state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the circuit, you can get the registers the circuit acts on from `eigs_circ.qregs`. You can then create another circuit using the returned quantum register, add an instruction to it (`initialize`) and then add these two circuits together. Your final code should look something like

```
qregs = eigs_circ.qregs         # NB this is a list
qc = QuantumCircuit(*qregs)
qc.initialize([0,1], 0)         # You need to specify the qubits to act on
overall_circ = qc + eigs_circ
```

The method for appending two circuits is [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/acb62a48755c34420d71e5680cdc237e2bd3d68b/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py#L270)

Comment: The line `qc = QuantumCircuit(qregs)` throws the error message `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'`. Nevertheless, `qc = QuantumCircuit(*qregs)` does the trick.

Comment: @NikPapadopoulos I'm glad this worked for you, I have updated the original answer with your correction - thanks!